# Efficient way to TRANSLATE every Nth string in bash or R

Tags: r, bash, awk, fastq

Thank you for taking the time to look at this.

I have a fastq file and I want to translate it to the complementary, but not the reverse complementary, something like this:

```
@Some header example:1:
ACTGAGACTCGATCA
+
S0m3_Qu4l1t13s&
```

Translated to

```
@Some header example:1:
TGACTCTGAGCTAGT
+
S0m3_Qu4l1t13s&
```

And the code I used is:

```
awk '{
  if(NR==100000){break} 
  else if((NR+2) % 4 ==0 ){ system("echo " $0 "| tr ATGC TACG") }
  else print $0}' MyFastqFyle.fastq > MyDesiredFile.fastq
```

And it works! but this approach is slooooooooow, even with small files (250M). I wonder which other way will get this done faster, doesn't matter if this is in R or bash or similar.

(I looked at BioStrings But I only found the reverse complimentary function,  and there are some issues with the "@" in the header instead of the ">")

Comment: `chartr("TAGC", "ATCG", "ACTGAGACTCGATCA")` in plain R code

Comment: how to apply that to the whole file (exclusive for 4th row)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is slow because you spawn a shell and a process in it for every changed line. Just do it with sed:

```
sed '2~4 y/ATGC/TACG/' MyFastqFyle.fastq > MyDesiredFile.fastq
```

This requires GNU sed, so I hope you're not on Mac OS X. If you are,

```
sed 'n; y/ATGC/TACG/; n; n' MyFastqFyle.fastq > MyDesiredFile.fastq
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks! That's it.
I wanted to accept this answer but I need to wait 6 more minutes, ha

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution using Biostrings (and ShortRead):

```
library(ShortRead)
raw <- sread(readFastq("MyFastqFyle.fastq"))
complemented <- complement(raw)
```